# Group Theory Example

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is an example of a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that $|G : H|$ is infinite? I am unsure of how to approach it as it was given as an open ended exercise. Would the group $\mathbb{Z}$ and any subgroup work?

Comment: It doesn't work with $\mathbb{Z}$ and **any** subgroup. But it **does** work with $\mathbb{Z}$ and **a** subgroup, specifically the subgroup $H = \{0\}$. (Oh, what a difference an "a" makes...)

Answer (score 6):

The index of a subgroup is essentially the "relative size".
If you take $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H = \{0\}$, then $G$ is "infinitely bigger", so $|G:H|$ is infinite.

To be more precise, the cosets of $H$ are all the singletons $\{n\}$ for $n \in G$, so you have infinitely many cosets.

Comment: So it is more relative size that is the comparison to the size of $G$

Comment: Yeah, if $G$ has three times as many elements as $H$, then $|G:H| = 3$, so in the same way $|\mathbb{Z}:\{0\}| = \infty$

Answer (score 2):

No, most subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$, which have index $n$. There is one subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ which has infinite index, the trivial group. It will have infinite index in any infinite group.

For other options, note that the group $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely generated, which means that $\mathbb{Z}$ will have infinite index in $\mathbb{Q},$ for example. Or $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of $\bigoplus^\infty\mathbb{Z}.$ For a finitely generated option, the singly generated group $\mathbb{Z}$ in the doubly generated free product $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite index. Or even just $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite index.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:  view $\mathbb{R}$ as a group under addition.  What well-known subgroups does $\mathbb{R}$ have?